# What insults did the Vulcan children use to try to goad Spock?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

In StarTrek 2009 young Spock says to the Vulcan kids:

> *This is your 35th attempt to elicit an emotional response from me.*

Which means there were at least 34 insults the Vulcan kids considered more effective in their bullying / experiment.

**Is there any info as to what those insults were?**

Comment: The better question is why, if Vulcans are supposed to be so smart, they took 35 goes to work out that they could upset him by *crackin' wise on his momma*.

Comment: @Valorum I guess because it's illogical 2b offended by slurs like that? Wouldn't it be more like to question his learning ability / competence? But i dont really know i am new at the star trek uni

Comment: Actually all the signs suggest that Vulcans are *very* family orientated. Mocking his origins should have been one of their first attempts, not their last.

Comment: @Valorum Hm. I tought they were like Ursula LeGuinns Tau Ceti guys for which the worst insult was 'you're not thinking logically'

Comment: Yo momma so fat, that when she hits Warp 1, she bounces.

Comment: Yo momma so ugly, everyone insists that she goes as a Breen for Halloween.

Comment: Yo momma so stupid, she hired a Pakled tutor.

Comment: Your mother is so lacking in the basics of logical discourse that when she encounters an ad hominem she assumes it's trying to get her to buy  some hominem.

Comment: Your mother is so foolish, that when she attempted to learn the basic tenets of Vulcan logic, it took her a great deal of time.

Comment: Yo momma so ugly, she came runner up in "Miss Medusan".

Comment: Your mother has so little hand-strength that when she attempts a nerve pinch people think she is giving them a massage.

Comment: Yo momma so stupid she tried to pilot a starship with the parking brake on.

Comment: Yo momma so dumb even Vulcans laugh at her.

Comment: "Which means there were at least 34 insults the vulcan kids considered more effective in their bullying / experiment." - logically, this is incorrect. It only means that there were 34 other *attempted* insults, not necessarily 34 that were more insulting.

Comment: Your question is so subjective, a Vulcan would VTC it :)

Comment: @Valorum the question could be objectively answered by pointing out that this is a frequently-used trope in Star Trek. Cf. Spock in TOS "Bread and Circuses":  _"They do seem to have escaped the carnage of your first three world wars, Doctor."_

Comment: I dare say everything that a vulcan could come up with that did NOT involve Spocks mother (as else they wouldn't have been taken by surprise when Spock went berserk).